# Facebook API, send post to users timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

My question is concerned about facebook API, more specificaly if there is any possibility to post something on user timeline (we have web store),for example we have new product and we want to inform our users(who logged in web store by facebook) about it by posting directly on their timeline.

So this is like open discussion about is that possible, legal and if there is any other better option to inform our users about new producs.

Greetings,
Ales

Answer (score 6):

No, this is of course not allowed.

Posts to user timelines must be created by the user. The user must decide that they want to post anything, and the message part of the post must be user generated, i.e. typed in by the user.

If you are that unclear on what is allowed and what not, then you should start reading here: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

> and if there is any other better option to inform our users about new producs.

Create a Facebook page, and post your stuff there. Let users like/follow that page, so that they will get to see its posts in their newsfeed.

(And if that is not enough for you, then look into Facebook ads.)